# Unequal pay for web and app developers with the same experience - How should I approach my boss?

Tags: communication, management, salary, work-environment, negotiation

I recently got a great opportunity to work at an American company that sponsors visas. I am currently a web front-end developer, and there are two other developers on the team. One is an iOS developer, and the other is an Android developer. All three of us have two years of experience, and we have been working together for about a month. The iOS developer had been working in the US on a J1 visa for a year at another company before transitioning to an H1B visa. The Android developer joined the team through the referral of the iOS developer.

The job posting I applied for stated that iOS, Android, and web developers with three years of experience would all receive the same salary of $6,500 per month. Before moving to the US, my salary was $3,500 per month, and I was vaguely told that my salary would increase after moving. However, after talking to the app developers, I learned that the Android developer's salary before moving to the US was $3,800 per month, and it would be adjusted to $6,500 per month after moving.

The app developers were also surprised and thought their salaries would be the same. Feeling that this was unfair, I asked my supervisor about the situation. The supervisor explained that since users will use apps more, more maintenance will be required for apps, and app developers generally earn slightly more than web developers in the US.

I pointed out that the job posting had stated that the salaries would be the same, and there will also be many web-related tasks for app developers. Currently, I am doing more work than the app developers. Therefore, I believe that we should all start on an equal footing.

The supervisor replied that the company would have to observe the situation a little more. There was no clear conclusion, but I was told to expect my salary to be between $6,000 and $6,500. However, the atmosphere suggested that it would be closer to $6,000.

I keep feeling that this situation is unfair. I did verify that app developers earn slightly more than web developers, but the job posting stated that developers with the same experience would receive the same salary. Currently, web development work is progressing more than app development.

I understand that $6,000 per month is not a small amount. However, my concern is that there is a difference from the beginning. I already know that there is a difference in salary, and the supervisor said they would observe my performance before determining my salary. However, the other developers' salaries were determined without observation, which feels unfair.

It doesn't seem that the app developers are exceptionally skilled compared to me; they are either on par with me or know less in some areas.

I am grateful for the opportunity to go to the US, and the company is even sponsoring my visa. The salary they are offering is not low either. However, I feel that I will always feel a sense of injustice whenever I receive my paycheck.

What I want to do in this situation is to clearly and firmly tell the supervisor that the starting line should be the same, whether here or in the US. And I believe that doing so will help me focus on my development work without distractions.

I would genuinely appreciate any heartfelt advice on my situation.

Comment: Pay is never equal except in commodity-skill situations or union shops.. Companies pay what they must to hire the skills they need, and some skills are in better supply than others. After that, raises and promotions in merit may or may not bring things level again. If you took the job, you agreed they were paying you enough; the fact that someone else held out for a better deal really is not relevant.

Comment: @keshlam Thank you for your advice. I know what you meant. Anyway, I have agreed with the salary regardless of how much the others get paid. But, what makes me hard to accept this situation is why the job posting stated that developers with the same experience would receive the same salary.. This part keeps me thinking it is unfiar.. Would you give me more advice on it?

Comment: Ask management? We don't know the details of their policies so we can't answer. Either they don't consider the experience exactly equal, or they don't consider that statement binding in one or both cases, or... Though frankly pursuing this isn't likely to lead anywhere good; focus instead on getting your next raise.

Comment: @keshlam Thank you for your valuable advice. You're right, it's better to focus on my own career growth rather than comparing myself to others. I understand that there will be plenty of opportunities in the future to achieve my goals and reach my full potential. Moving forward, I will concentrate on improving my skills and making the most of the opportunities that come my way. Thanks again for your guidance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in the various comments beneath your posting:

*Compensation of human labour mostly follows market principle and not «fairness», which is highly subjective.*

Rather than counting on fairplay, you should be making visible the value you add/create with your labour to any future employer. Which justifies the compensation that you expect.

You could also be taking an underpaid position to relocate into that region and than use your local presence (social networking) to find a better paid position.

Wishing you all the best.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful response. I understand that the market plays a significant role in determining compensation, and I will focus on demonstrating the value I bring to the table. Your suggestion of considering an underpaid position to establish a presence in the region and then leveraging my local network for better opportunities is an interesting approach. I will definitely consider that option while planning my future career moves. I appreciate your well wishes and advice. Thank you!